# Table view header, storyboard, Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, xcode11

In **XCode 11**,

- new storyboard,
- add a `UIViewController` (sic: NOT a table view controller),
- hit the + symbol top right,
- drag a table view into the view controller.
- Perhaps add four constraints so it is simply full-screen.

Table view attributes inspector, perhaps set Prototype Cells to not-zero, say 2.

**How do you now add a header view to the table view?**

(The header view should (obviously) be able to handle dynamic height content.)

Comment: Hey @Fattie, go select a UIView then drag into up of the UITableView, then it must be a seperator with solid blue color. It present that your UIView will be added as UITableView HeaderView. This is basic way of add it. Am I get wrong your question?

Comment: Try the drag into top of the UITableView

Comment: hehe, just select a UIView and drag into the top of the frame of the UITableView, so you *must* see blue indicator/seperator. Then when you run the simulator it worked like headerView, so you are able to do change headerView''s color, you can see the difference. If you won't do it I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way of to achieve adding `HeaderView` to `UITableView` is.

Plus `+` button from Top Bar and Select an `UIView`

Then in hierarchy add the exact bottom of the `UITableView`.

See the image.

[image]

Your `UIView` element must be like that in the `hierarchy`.

Then the `UIView` calculations for dynamic view upon to you.

(You can create an `IBOutlet` of the this `UIView` and do some calculation in your `UIViewController`. )

Comment: But it doesn't "SAY" anything, it does not indicate in any way it is a header view???

Comment: Hmm, actually so good question. Like you said, there is no description about it being header view, ( must search documentation). But the both HeaderView and FooterView can be manipulate with `UIView`, so you can handle it.

Comment: And I have to say that, you can achieve it by dragging into directly bottom of the `UITableView` for `FooterView` and top of the `UITableView` for the `HeaderView`, but I can not get any screenshot because when I pressing `Command + Shift` combination, the blue indicator is not showing up. So there's some ways to achieve this action.

Comment: I am still scared to do it because it is so weird  ::O

Comment: @Fattie when I on computer I will edit it as height but now I do not sure, I don’t want to write wrong something